# Default values in json object based on contents of other objects in the same array

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm pretty lost right now and have been working on this for about 6 days now so forgive me if this is a bit confusing. I'm using NVD3 to display some graphs based on data that comes in from BigQuery. All the data coming in is correct and so is the graph implementation, the issue is the actual JSON data. The multi bar chart requires that each "set" of data have the same dates and same number of values under the initial array. Based off my data, sometimes there will be missing values if a user didn't log an event or something that day.

The general idea of what I'm trying to do here is loop through the initial json and append on the "missing" values. For example this would be the initial data that I get out of BigQuery and my API:

```
[
  "t1":{
    "target": "t1",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        16.0,
        1483747200.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484352000.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  "t2":{
    "target": "t2",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        10.0,
        1483660800.0
      ],
      [
        19.0,
        1484006400.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484956800.0
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

You can see here that the first object has a datapoints array with 2 values, object two has a datapoints array with 3 values. The 1 index of the datapoints array contains a UNIX date, every datapoints array within the entire object must have an array with the date and then 0 for a default value. So the formatted data would look something like this:

```
[
  "t1":{
    "target": "t1",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        16.0,
        1483747200.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484352000.0
      ],
      [
        0.0,
        1483660800.0
      ],
      [
        0.0,
        1484006400.0
      ],
      [
        0.0,
        1484956800.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  "t2":{
    "target": "t2",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        10.0,
        1483660800.0
      ],
      [
        19.0,
        1484006400.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484956800.0
      ],
      [
        0.0,
        1483747200.0
      ],
      [
        0.0,
        1484352000.0
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I really have no idea where to go from here and any help whatsoever would be extremely helpful. I've been working on this for days and at this point am just grinding my gears. Thanks

Basically, each value that's found in one array but not in others should take the timestamp but set the first value/index to 0.

I should also mention that the query is only querying for 30 days back so at most each one of the datapoints arrays would have 30 arrays.

Comment: If you are familiar with basic JavaScript loops and Date objects, this is trivial.  Have you tried looking into these on MDN or tutorials?

Comment: I've looked everywhere, it's more of a logic thing than an actual code issue I think. I'm not the best at using javascript to do this type of task. I know that I have to loop through each array but as to what to do with the values, I'm not sure. Normally, I would just move on from this for a few days and come back to solve it but I don't really have that choice... deadlines.

Comment: Is the time constraint by ms (exact) or just by day?

Comment: The dates/times are coming in from `UNIX_SECONDS` with bigquery. The time stamps are set to 12AM on that day, so they would be just the day.

Comment: So you have two starting arrays, t1 and t2,  you want two resultant arrays that are both the union of the two with either t1[0] = 0 if absent from t2 or t2[0] = 0 if absent from t1.  array concat to create your result arrays, then iterate the result arrays and lookup the value from the source arrays and substitute zero if not found.

Comment: I actually have many more arrays than just these two here, somewhere around 10 - 15. Basically the intial data is an object of arrays with a target and an array of arrays (datapoints). When a datapoint is not found in another datapoints array, I want to add it with the 0 index set to 0.

Comment: No matter how many arrays, Chris' suggestion is pretty good

Comment: I'd recommend, if possible, to move this up to the server then and get your data feed in the right output rather than trying to implement in code.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness No, I don't want to map each 0 index of each array to another array. I need to scan each one and when a value is found that isn't in one array within the datapoints array, set the 0 to 0 and the timestamp to the found timestamp.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I said above?  If not found in t2 then t1[0] = 0???

Comment: I named the arrays above. So if t1.datapoints is missing datapoint arrays that exist in t2.datapoints, add the array found in t2.datapoints with the 0 index of it set to 0 but the 1 index the same value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do a bit of data processing first to get all of the dates, then it's just a matter of filling in the actual data for each date.

```js
const json = [
  {
    "target": "t1",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        16.0,
        1483747200.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484352000.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "t2",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        10.0,
        1483660800.0
      ],
      [
        19.0,
        1484006400.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484956800.0
      ]
    ]
  }
]

// using es6 set
const dates = new Set()

json.forEach( x => x.datapoints.map( dp => dates.add(dp[1]) ) )

// all dates are there
dates.forEach( d => console.log(d) )

const fillDp = dp => {
    return Array.from(dates).sort().map( d => dp.find( x => x[1] === d ) || [0,d] )
}

const result = json.map( x => Object.assign(x, {datapoints: fillDp(x.datapoints)}) )
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].datapoints))
```

Comment: You sir are an absolute life saver. From my initial "testing" this seems to be doing exactly what I want it to do. I'll accept the answer once I'm certain it's correct. Thanks again!!

Comment: What about adding ordering to the new dates? I need to be able to order them by either earlier to later or later to earlier.

Comment: You can convert the dates set to an array and do a sort from there.

Comment: That wont work because they need to be linked with the values in order to work with NVD3.js. Isn't there just a way to sort them while appending to the array?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Updated snippet to use a `map` to create the datapoints arrays

Answer (score 0):

Below is a quick and dirty solution. Note that I added an additional entry to the sample you provided so that both data objects contain a data point with a common date.

```
var orig= [
  {
    "target": "t1",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        16.0,
        1483747200.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484352000.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1483660800.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "t2",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        10.0,
        1483660800.0
      ],
      [
        19.0,
        1484006400.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1484956800.0
      ]
    ]
  }
];
console.log('Original Data', JSON.stringify(orig));

// Get a list of all the datapoint dates
var dates = [];
orig.forEach(function(item) {
  item.datapoints.forEach(function(dp) {
    var date = dp[1];
    dates.push(date);
  })
});
console.log('All Dates', JSON.stringify(dates));

// Remove duplicates from array
dates = dates.filter(function (el, i, arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(el) === i;
});
console.log('Unique Dates', JSON.stringify(dates));

// Check each item in the original array for records for each date and add a
// 0 value entry if the date entry is missing
dates.forEach(function(dt) {
  orig.forEach(function(item, itemIndex) {
    var hasEntry = false;

    item.datapoints.forEach(function(dp) {
      if (dp[1] === dt) hasEntry = true;
    });

    if (!hasEntry) {
      item.datapoints.push([0, dt]);
    }
  });
});

console.log('Updated Data', JSON.stringify(orig));
```

And here is the corresponding plunker so you can see it in action: https://plnkr.co/edit/K1NK2Xx8RNrqyp7yZ3n2?p=preview

Comment: Where in this code is it getting pushed to the new array/object? Seems like this might work.

Comment: In the `if(!hasEntry)` statement, meaning a matching entry was not found for that date, we push the entry into the `updated` array.

Comment: is there a way I can push it to the orgin array? That's what I really need, not a new array.

Comment: Code and plunker updated so that original array is modified instead of creating a new object.